# Windows Mobile PPC Microphone

Tags: windows-mobile

I need to be able to mute/unmute the ppc mic when i have a SIP Push To Talk call; Anyone with the knowledge please offer advice; I have tried using the phoneSetGain(...) API but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is NOT what you want to do. Just collect and discard the samples when ptt is not activated. There are a variety of reasons for doing it this way, the biggest of which is that you will be mich more responsive (you can start sending samples as soon as you receive the button press event, otherwise, you have to wait for all the hardware changes to take effect.

Comment: @Shane C. Mason; thank you for your response; i have some 'proprietary PTT' - the way i determine that a SIP call is PTT is based on certain pre-set parameters thus the need to mute/unmute the mic.